# React Application + API authentication

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, axios, express-session

I've set up an API to access my backend, and implemented express sessions to authenticate users.

When using Postman to login, and then access protected GET requests, it works fine.

But the React SPA that i'm building can't seem to use the session to authenticate itself, after logging in.

I tried many suggestions i found online (changing CORS headers, using explicit cookie setting in React, changing the way i store my sessions,...) but none seem to solve the issue.

I'll try to include the relevant Code snippets:

### Server-side (REST API)

**Session & CORS middleware:**

```
//Session Middleware
api.use(session({
    genid: (req) => {
        console.log('Inside session middleware');
        console.log(req.sessionID)
        return uuid()
    },
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 60000
    },
    secret:"123",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:true,
        store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection:db,
        clear_interval: 3600
    })
}));

// CORS
api.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    next();
})
```

**Login Function & Passport auth:**

```
exports.login = (req,res,next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local',(err,user,info) =>{
        //... (login handling)
    })(req,res,next);
}

// Passport Middleware
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    (username, password, done) => {
        Promotor.findOne({username:username,password:password}, (err,user) =>{
            if (err) {
                done(err,null);
            }
            if (!user){
                done(null,false,{message:'Invalid Credentials!'})
            } else {
                done(null,user)
            }
        });
    }
));

// Passport serializing
passport.serializeUser((user,done) => {
    done(null,user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id,done) => {
    Promotor.findById(id,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            done(err,false);
        } else {
            done(null,user);
        }
    })
})
```

**Protected GET function**

(isAuthenticated() Returns false when using axios from my SPA)

```
exports.getNameById = (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.session)
    console.log(req._passport)
    if(!req.isAuthenticated()){ //RETURNS FALSE IN REACT & TRUE IN POSTMAN
        return res.status(401).send();
    }

    return controller.getDocumentById(Promotor,'firstname lastname',req,res);
}
```

### Client-side (React SPA)

**Axios Request to Log In**

(Works in both Postman & app, and correctly creates session)

```
handleSubmit(e){
  console.log("Trying To log in");
  axios
    .post(`${api_url}/promotor/login`,{username: this.state.username, password:this.state.password})
    .then( (res) => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState(() => ({toClientHome: true, id:res.data.id}));
      }
    });
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Axios request to access protected GET request**

(GET request works in postman when session cookie is set, but not with axios)

```
getFullName(id) {
  axios
    .get(`${api_url}/promotor/name/${id}`,{
      withCredentials: true
    })
    .then((res) => {
      //... rest of the code
    });
}
```

Comment: I recommend token system for authentication instead of cookie-based sessions. JWT is a good choice for now.

Comment: @DatTran Yeah, while searching for answers i learned that JWT is probably a better solution than the session bassed approach i'm currently using. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please put your cors middleware code on the top of your file(after all imports)!!

```
api.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    next();
})
```

Then try it again.

Comment: Thanks, this solution ended my several hour research! Do you mind elaborating why this has to be done this way?

Comment: We use the cors middleware function in express before we define our routes so that it will allow the access for different resource to your defined domains. With out giving access how can your get resources. In Javascript file is compiled from top to bottom line by line.

Answer (score 0):

```
api.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
   
})
```